# Solr join returns zero results

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Solr 6.4.2. I have defined 2 cores:

- **companies**, with the fields '**Id, Town, Name, Type, ManagerId**'
- **users**, with the fields '**Id, Login, ManagerId, Email**'

In users core the field ManagerId is parent-child relation (ManagerId->Id).

Companies and users are related by companies.ManagerId->users.Id

I am trying to build a very simple join query:

```
{!join from=ManagerId to=Id fromIndex=users}Login:someuser1
```

url looks like:

```
?q=*:*&fq={!join%20from=ManagerId%20to=Id%20fromIndex=users}Login:someuser1
```

nothing works, I always get zero results. I just want to understand how Solr join works. It seems to me that there is a big difference in understanding between Solr joins and SQL joins.

In fact I want to do the queries like:

- get all docs from users by company Types
- get companies by user managers

Right now I always get zero results no matter how I write the join query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the company core (assuming you want the get all companies run by a certain manager login):

- `login:someuser1` is the filter condition you put on the child table, this should be the manager login you are looking for
- `from=ManagerId` should be the id on the child table, so this is wrong
- `to=id` is the field on the parent table that relates to the child table, so this is wrong
- `fromIndex` is the child table, this is correct

  ```
  {!join from=ManagerId to=Id fromIndex=users}Login:someuser1
  ```